# Saved Web Part lists data but errors on link through

Tags: 2010, web-part, error, discussion-board

Im having a problem with a saved web part which lists recent discussion board posts from a different subsite within the same site collection. The web part shows all of the data correctly but when I try to click on the title of the post, the link doesnt work and I get an error which states that the list doesnt exist, even though it most definitely does!

No item exists at
https://sharepoint.com/sites/sitecollection/subsite1/SitePages/Home.aspx?RootFolder=/sites/sitecollection/forums/Lists/forum1/TestMessage&FolderCTID=0x0120020022320313F7130345BBA1303493FF7E68&View={32E432A8-E0B3-4492-8B39-CA9935E1F2C9}&TopicsView=https://sharepoint/sites/sitecollection/subsite1/SitePages/Home.aspx
It may have been deleted or renamed by another user.

The RootFolder URL is correct if I append it to our sharepoint url and takes me to the post if I remove all the other stuff after TestMessage. The full URL given by the error doesnt work.

I created the web part on the forum site and then using SPD2010 saved it to the Web Part Gallery, when asked if I wanted the web part to always link to the forum site and not a link relative to the subsite, I said Yes.

It looks exactly how I want it but the links through to the posts just dont work. Can anyone help me out with this please? We're using SharePoint Server 2010 btw.

Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem. the webpart displayed fine but the click through gave me a "page not found error". I finally deleted the subject view and re-added it. the URL worked fine after that. Unfortunately, it did not go to the details I expected but it was the right list and no error. The next problem will be going to the flat view.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a mixture of arguments, which might give you the feeling it does work, but not entirelly accurate. The reason being that saving (exporting) web parts would preserve references to prior lists & view identifiers (different per list always) whereas site collection relative Urls could adapt themselves to context. The only one that could be the same is the Content Type Id as lists are keeping it.

So I would suggest you validate both that the list Id and View Id are proper, by going to the target list settings and in the address bar you shall get the proper Guid (it is Url encoded but replacing characters with {} and - should get you there). Do the same for the Views.

Comment: I checked and both IDs are correct. As I mentioned above, I can see all of my data correctly, it seems as though its just the link behind the item title that is incorrect? If I hover over an item, I can open it's contextual menu and choose things like Edit Item and View Item. If I click on these options then it brings up the new, edit and display forms as expected. So I'm thinking that the problem is the hyperlink options associated to my item titles? Currently the link is set as {$FolderURL} but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Ok, I managed to get the url working behind the item titles by changing the settings in the hyperlink options menu. Unfortunately, SPD didnt like this and the only way I could reopen the page in SPD was to delete the web part. I think Im going to delete all the web parts and start again. Is there a better way for me to do this rather than saving web parts from another subsite into the web part gallery? It seems like such a simple thing to do, display a selection of recent forum posts from one subsite on a range of different subsites under the same site collection?